# Add Javascript into Python created html

Tags: javascript, python, html

Hi i have a python script that creates a single html file and i cannot figure out how to add javascript into it

```
import pathlib
import os
 
html = ""
 
for file in pathlib.Path(".").iterdir():
    if file.is_file():
        if str(file).endswith(".png"):
            html += f"<center><img src='{file}'/ height=100%></center><br>"
            
 
with open("index2.html", "w") as outputfile:
    outputfile.write(html)
 
os.startfile("index2.html")
```

So far ive tried

```
import pathlib
import os
 
html = ""
 
for file in pathlib.Path(".").iterdir():
    if file.is_file():
        if str(file).endswith(".png"):
            html += f"<center><img src='{file}'/ height=50%></center><br><script>var imagesrc = document.getElementById("image.png").src;"

 
with open("index2.html", "w") as outputfile:
    outputfile.write(html)
 
os.startfile("index2.html")
```

but that doesnt seem to work at all

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a `script.js` file in your directory:

```
# File.py
html += "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"script.js\"></script>"
```

---

If you want it directly in the `.html` file, you can do this:

```
html += f"<script type=\"text/javascript\">{javascript_content}</script>"
```

Comment: Im trying to get it into just one html file if possible

Comment: In this case you only have to copy-paste the code into a script tag, I'm editing my answer

Answer (score 0):

That probably didn't worked because your " (quotation mark) is interrupting your string at "image.png", you could use a single apostrophe, or just escape it using backslash.

```
html += f"<center><img src='{file}'/ height=50%></center><br><script>var imagesrc = document.getElementById(\"image.png\").src;"
```